# html dependency error when rendering slide presentation in quarto

Tags: rstudio, rendering, quarto, presentation

I am working in the latest version of R and RStudio.

I kept having an html dependency path error when trying to render revealjs slides in quarto. The problem is with a missing Rtmp folder that I have on one computer but not my laptop where I am also doing work.

I updated all my packages on my lapptop, even did an uninstall and install for R and RStudio. The missing temp folder did not appear and I can't figure out what package this temp folder is related to: Rtmpg1ILdQ

So when I go to render the revealjs presentation to preview it - it gets an error at the end of the knit to say that it cannot find this folder. I've solved the issue by copying the temp folder from one computer to the other, but I would like to figure out what is causing this and how to fix it without having to do that.

I wanted to render a quarto revealjs presentation that has leaflet maps and ggplot visualizations. It failed to render and said that the error was related to not finding a path to an html dependency.

Comment: Can you share the the code that causes the issue?